# How does optparse-applicative bash autocompletion work?

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

I'm building a brainfuck compiler. The executable accepts two commands `$ brainfuck compile ...` and `$ brainfuck run`. I want the executable to auto complete when pressing tab. E.g. writing `$ brainfuck com` and then pressing tab should generate `$ brainfuck compile`.

```hs
data Command = Compile CompileArgs | Run RunArgs
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = execute =<< execParser opts
  where
    opts = info (helper <*> argsParser) fullDesc

execute :: Command -> IO ()
execute (Compile args)  = compile args
execute (Run args)      = run args

argsParser :: Parser Command
argsParser = subparser (compileCommand <> runCommand)
  where
    compileCommand  = command "compile" $ info compileOptions $ progDesc "Compile brainfuck to an executable"
    runCommand      = command "run"     $ info runOptions     $ progDesc "Execute brainfuck code"
```

There is a section on optparse's github page [here](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/wiki/Bash-Completion), but I don't really understand it.

The function `completeWith :: Options.Applicative.Builder.Internal.HasCompleter f => [String] -> Mod f a` looks quite similar to `command :: String -> ParserInfo a -> Mod CommandFields a` which I'm already using. So I figured I could use it and just combine them with `<>` but it turns out that `CommandFields` is not an instance of `HasCompleter`.

How are you supposed to get the auto completion to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After RTFM'ing a bit I found out how to configure the auto completion.
`completeWith` is applied when constructing the parsers for the individual arguments.
Like so:

```hs
data CompileArgs = CompileArgs
  {
    debug :: Bool,
    optimizations :: OptimizationLevel,
    file :: String
  }
  deriving (Show, Read)

compileArgsParser :: Parser CompileArgs
compileArgsParser = CompileArgs
  <$> switch (
    long "debug" <>
    help "Outputs object and assembly files")
  <*> option auto (
    long "optimization-level" <>
    value All <>
    metavar "LEVEL" <>
    help "all | none, default: all" <>
    completeWith ["all", "none"])
  <*> argument str (
    metavar "FILE" <>
    help "brainfuck source code" <>
    action "file")
  <**> helper
```

`action` is an instruction to bash on how auto complete. `"file"` means auto complete with any file or directory. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) page for more info.

In order for these auto completions to kick in you need to generate a script and make sure that script is sourced. By convention it's placed under `/etc/bash_completion.d/` when using bash.

```sh
brainfuck --bash-completion-script `which brainfuck` | sudo tee /etc/bash_completion.d/brainfuck
```

in my case where my program is called `brainfuck`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but after reading the documentation, it seems to me that by calling `execParser` in `main`, your program automatically supports the required options for command complete. You just need to run your program with `--bash-completion-script` as documented to generate a shell script, and then load that script to bash.